# SharePoint Excel URL to Python Pandas DataFrame -Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sharepoint, streamlit

**Issue:** uploading large file to Streamlit-> need a workaround for file size related issues.

**Is there a way to create a pandas df from just a file SharePoint file url link?**

I solved it for Google Drive url link but cannot figure out SharePoint.

**Potential Solution:** Create a url link from SharePoint and load the excel/csv file in as a pandas df.

```html
import pandas as pd

url = 'google drive url'
path = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='+url.split('/')[-2]
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Comment: what I used to read csv from google sheets: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../export?gid=...&format=csv`. might help you

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm trying to make the SharePoint excel share link/url to work without login credentials such as other posts on here.

Answer (score 0):

yea you can use https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client

```
download_path = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), os.path.basename(FILE_URL))
with open(download_path, "wb") as local_file:
   ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(FILE_URL).download(local_file).execute_query()
```

then read the download_path

df = pd.read_csv(downloadpath)

don't for get to del out the temp file !

The Library is amazing, you can also read the sharepoint file directly in bytes
Ex:

```
def read_csv(ctx, relative_url, pandas=False):
    # relative_url = "/sites/myLib/Folder/test.csv" #TEST
    # ctx = auth()
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)
    bytes_data = response.content
    try:
        s = str(bytes_data, 'utf8')
    except Exception as e:
        print('utf8 encoding error')
        print(relative_url, e)
        try:
            s = str(bytes_data, 'cp1252')
        except Exception as e:
            print('CRITIAL ERROR cp1252 encoding error')
            print(relative_url, e)
    if pandas == False:
        return s
    else:
        data = StringIO(s)
        return data
```

I use panadas variable bc my final code looks like

```
df= pd.read_csv(read_csv(ctx=ctx, relative_url=FILE_URL, pandas=True), dtype=str, keep_default_na=False) # read master qrd db
```